# PHP overriding parent method that isn't called directly

Tags: php

I have two classes parent and children:

```
class Post
{
    public function save()
    {
        $this->update_data();
        $this->custom_updates();
        $this->load();
    }

    protected function custom_updates() { /* empty */ }
}
class Event extends Post
{
    protected function custom_updates()
    {
        //perform custom updates specific for Event objects
    }
}

$Event = new Event();
$Event->save();
```

when I execute above code the method custom_updates() will be called from original Post class, not the child Event class. Is there any clever way to override parent method, so it will be used by the object ? Or the only option is to modify the method that is being called, in this example save()

```
class Event extends Post
{
    public function save()
    {
        $this->update_data();
        $this->custom_updates();
        $this->load();
    }

    protected function custom_updates()
    {
        //perform custom updates specific for Event objects
    }
}
```

Comment: *"when I execute above code the method `custom_updates()` will be called from original `Post` class, not the child `Event` class."* -- this is not correct. The method `custom_updates()` from the class of `$this` is invoked. Check it out: https://3v4l.org/SFaLU This is how inheritance works in PHP.

Comment: The code you posted overrides the parent method. This basic is a basic oop principle.Please check once again.

Comment: The method called will be the overriding child method - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/leZ3X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code, everything should be working, try doing some `var_dump` in your methods and see what the output will be

Comment: My bad, I tested this before and it didn't work. Now when I try again it works perfectly fine. My mistake and I apologize for stupid question.